# How can I do Selenium WebDriver right? - High Level Organization of Automated Tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I've started automating the testing of my website with Selenium WebDriver, but I am not sure how to organize my test cases at a high level. I am using Python and making use of the `unittest` class).

Here's a scenario of 4 tests

1. Logging In
2. Filling out Form A part 1
3. Filling out Form A part 2
4. Submitting Form A

Test 1 is the most basic - nothing depends on it.

Test 2 depends on the user being logged in (test 1).

Test 3 depends on the user logging in and filling out the preceding form part (tests 1 and 2). I'd also like this test to be carried out immediately after test 2 (where the webdriver wouldn't have to log in again).

Test 4 depends on the user being logged in and having both parts of Form A being filled out (tests 1, 2, and 3)

How can I manage these dependencies effectively so I can reuse the code for each test case?

Comment: This is very difficult to answer properly! The best advice that I can give you: ask your developers how they structure the different units of the app, and try to follow that. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: @SiKing the above scenario details how one section of the app is structured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use Page Object Pattern.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern

Some more links:

http://assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects